# Erlang getting the exact size in memory of a SSL connection

Tags: ssl, erlang, size

Is there a way in erlang to get exactly how much memory a SSL connection takes ?

Right now I'm kinda guessing by dividing the whole beam.smp size (minus the init size) in memory by the number of connected clients...

I'm using R15B01

The SSL connection is handled by a gen_server, doing

```
process_info(spawn(Fun), memory).
```

give me after gc calling:

```
{memory,2108}
```

This clearly does not contain the SSL socket connection size.

Comment: There is no such thing as the 'size of an SSL connection'. Question is meaningless and cannot be answered in its present form. Please try again.

Comment: @EJP : What is meaningless about asking to know how much memory a SSL connection takes with Erlang ?

Comment: Because (1) it isn't clear what you are asking about: if you're talking about the data coming down it, you can't know without reading it all; if you're talking about the incremental cost of just opening the connection, (2) it varies over time, and according to how many certificates the server sends you, and how many cipher suites you support, and which one the server chooses, etc etc. It just isn't a well defined quantum.

Comment: @EJP : You are clearly over thinking this... What I need is a way to get the size in memory of SSL ("structure") connection on Erlang at a certain time... No matter Cipher suites, certificates, ..., I'm not looking for calculating the size by hand, but getting it from the VM. I'm asking this especially to evaluate which parameters are less memory consuming.

Comment: parameters such as protocol, cipher suite, ...? And it still changes over time depending on whether you have/haven't done the handshake etc.

Comment: @EJP: exactly, that's why I need a function that gives the size in memory at a certain time, that will help me figure out where the memory is allocated, whether before or after the handshake..

Comment: Both, of course. Once the handshake has completed there is extra memory, i.e. the session ID and the session key, and a reference to the session object. This is not a vast amount of data, less than 1K. Hard to know why you think it's important really.

Comment: @EJP: my goal is trying to reduce the SSL session object size at a minimum in order to save some RAM. For that I'm trying multiple parameters (on the VM and on the System). But I need numeric data, in order to know which are really relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that even to handle a single SSL connection Erlang starts several separate processes (certificate db, ssl manager, ssl session, etc) and each of those processes might have a separate storage for its data. Thus it is hard to give a definitive answer how much memory each connection takes as there is quite a few places which keep book keeping information about the connection.

If you need an estimate, I would do the following:

1. Started a SSL server and a SSL client as described at http://pdincau.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/a-brief-introduction-to-ssl-with-erlang/
2. Saved `TotalMemory1 = proplists:get_value(total, memory()).` in the server session.
3. Tried to open 99 more client connections from a separate client session.
4. Calculated `TotalMemory2 = proplists:get_value(total, memory()).`
5. Found out amortized amount of memory a single connection takes by dividing `(TotalMemory2 - TotalMemory1)/99`.

Comment: Well I guess I secretly knew the answer, that it was not possible out-of-the-box... However I will try your solution, it seems less crapy than mine to estimate the socket size.